# Remove already voted to close questions from the "Close" review tab

Tags: feature-request

When I flag a post from the *Flags* tab, it gets removed on reload. I'd like to see the same thing happen with entries in the *Close* tab.

There are currenty 17 questions in *Recent Votes* and I voted on half of them - I don't want to open and try to vote on all of those questions to see which ones are new.